# Get data from file input in JQuery

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, base64, html-input

I actually have a file input and I would like to retrieve the Base64 data of the file.

I tried:

```
$('input#myInput')[0].files[0]
```

to retrieve the data. But it only provides the name, the length, the content type but not the data itself.

I actually need these data to send them to Amazon S3

I already test the API and when I send the data through html form with encode type "multipart/form-data" it works.

I use this plugin : http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

And this plugins gives me a preview of the picture and I retrieve data in the src attribute of the image preview. But when I send these data to S3 it does not work. I maybe need to encode the data like "multipart/form-data" but I don't know why.

Is there a way to retrieve these data without using an html form?

Comment: In order to have contents you're going to need to upload it in some fashion (iframe, ajax, flash, or traditional form).

Comment: The file must be uploaded to the server first.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the browser supports the new File API (see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: I'm actually using this plugin http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload and I can get a preview of the file so the data are somewhere.

Comment: in that case the "data" will be on the server. You'll have to output the data to the client (browser) before you can access it via Javascript/jQuery

Comment: I think that the plugin that I use already do that. I can retrieve some data in the image preview file but that's just a part of the data not all the file data.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can try the FileReader API. Do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>        
      function handleFileSelect()
      {               
        if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
          alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
          return;
        }   
      
        var input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        if (!input) {
          alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
          alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
          alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
        }
        else {
          var file = input.files[0];
          var fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = receivedText;
          //fr.readAsText(file);
          //fr.readAsBinaryString(file); //as bit work with base64 for example upload to server
          fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
      }
      
      function receivedText() {
        document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result));
      }           
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
    <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='handleFileSelect();' />
    <div id="editor"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and that works. I retrieved the information but it's not well encoded. For a file I get `\xc3\xbf\xc3` instead of getting this encode `\xff\xd8\xff` for the 3 first characters of my picture. What should I use to get the second encode for my picture?

Comment: @kschaeffler try fr.readAsDataURL(file); this is function reading  Base64 datas, but i haven't tested it yet.

Comment: actually this function give me not enough data. that's already what I have from the preview that I use in the plugin jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload. I think that the data I retrieve are not Base64 encoded and this is the problem, but I'm not sure

Comment: I actually need the same encode data that I retrieve when I post through html form with the "multipart/form-data" encode type

Answer (score 245):

input file element:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

get file :

```
var myFile = $('#fileinput').prop('files');
```

Comment: Perfect solution! thank you. 
Improvement for single upload, index 0.
var myFile = $('#fileinput').prop('files')[0];

Comment: Excellent, got my script working with Cloudinary without having to submit a form. Drag, drop, upload :)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great answer !! you can then move the variable with `$('.myClass').prop('files', myFile );`

Answer (score 54):

I created a form data object and appended the file:

```
var form = new FormData(); 
form.append("video", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]);
```

and i got:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryNczYRonipfsmaBOK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video"; filename="Wildlife.wmv"
Content-Type: video/x-ms-wmv
```

in the headers sent. I can confirm this works because my file was sent and stored in a folder on my server. If you don't know how to use the FormData object there is some documentation online, but not much. [Form Data Object Explination by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 49):

Html:

```
<input type="file" name="input-file" id="input-file">
```

jQuery:

```
var fileToUpload = $('#input-file').prop('files')[0];
```

We want to get first element only, because prop('files') returns array.

Answer (score 22):

`input` element, of type `file`

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

On your `input` change use the `FileReader` object and read your `input` file property:

```
$('#fileInput').on('change', function () {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      var data = fileReader.result;  // data <-- in this var you have the file data in Base64 format
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL($('#fileInput').prop('files')[0]);
});
```

FileReader will load your file and in `fileReader.result` you have the file data in Base64 format (also the file content-type (MIME), text/plain, image/jpg, etc)

Answer (score 17):

FileReader API with jQuery, simple example.

```js
( function ( $ ) {
 // Add click event handler to button
 $( '#load-file' ).click( function () {
  if ( ! window.FileReader ) {
   return alert( 'FileReader API is not supported by your browser.' );
  }
  var $i = $( '#file' ), // Put file input ID here
   input = $i[0]; // Getting the element from jQuery
  if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
   file = input.files[0]; // The file
   fr = new FileReader(); // FileReader instance
   fr.onload = function () {
    // Do stuff on onload, use fr.result for contents of file
    $( '#file-content' ).append( $( '<div/>' ).html( fr.result ) )
   };
   //fr.readAsText( file );
   fr.readAsDataURL( file );
  } else {
   // Handle errors here
   alert( "File not selected or browser incompatible." )
  }
 } );
} )( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<input type='button' id='load-file' value='Load'>
<div id="file-content"></div>
```

To read as text... uncomment `//fr.readAsText(file);` line and comment `fr.readAsDataURL(file);`

Answer (score 6):

Get file using jquery

element html:

```
 <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

jquery code:

```
 $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]
```

this work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="row form-group my-2">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <label for="inpImage" class="m-2 pointer">
                                <img src="src/img/no-image.jpg" id="img-visor" height="120" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
                            </label>
                            <input type="file" class="visually-hidden" accept="image/*" name="picture" id="inpImage">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#inpImage').change(()=>{
const file = $('#inpImage').prop("files")[0];
const imagen = URL.createObjectURL(file);
console.log(URL.createObjectURL(file));
$('#img-visor').attr('src', imagen);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="~/fileupload/fileinput.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/fileupload/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Download above files named fileinput add the path i your index page.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-5" style="margin: 0 0 0 8px;">
<input id="uploadFile1" name="file" type="file" class="file-loading"       
 `enter code here`accept=".pdf" multiple>
</div>

<script>
        $("#uploadFile1").fileinput({
            autoReplace: true,
            maxFileCount: 5
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>        
      function handleFileSelect()
      {               
        if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
          alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
          return;
        }   
      
        var input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        if (!input) {
          alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
          alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
          alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");               
        }
        else {
          var file = input.files[0];
          var fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = receivedText;
          //fr.readAsText(file);
          //fr.readAsBinaryString(file); //as bit work with base64 for example upload to server
          fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
      }
      
      function receivedText() {
        document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result));
      }           
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput"/>
    <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='handleFileSelect();' />
    <div id="editor"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.