# JavaScript, File and Blob objects

Tags: javascript, file, blob, document

I have a link of questions coming since I am developing a Flickr interface. Although I am not that new to developing code in languages like PHP, C++, Java and so on, but there are things that I must have missed in class because I just do not understand what to do, or more importantly how to think.

1. When I upload a file from the desktop, it will accessible through the input that is used for the upload, but where is the actual file data located? When I use the following method to fetch the data I get a File object with some details but the raw data is missing. Why?

   ```
   function processUpload(event) {
       "use strict";

       var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer"),
           data = event.target.files,
           file = null,
           i = null;

       while (container.childNodes.length > 0) {
           container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]);
       }
       for (i = 0; file = data[i]; i++) {
           if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
               continue;
           }
           files.push(file);
       }
       loadImages();
   }
   ```
2. In my current code for the Flickr interface, I can load data from their Feeds and I get images but these are not of the same type as the images that I load from the desktop. To create File objects out of this data I do the following in my JavaScript code. I'm new to jQuery to excuse the mess. How do I update the code below so it will create the same kind of a File object, regarding an image, as if I would upload from the desktop? Perhaps it's not important right now but I rather that they are of equal type before I continue with this Flickr interface.

   ```
   function fetchImages() {
       var blob = [
           new Blob([], {}), [], new Uint16Array([32])
       ];

       $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
           tagmode: "any",
           format: "json",
       }, function (data) {
           for (var i = 0; data.items.length; i++) {
               files.push(new File(blob, data.items[i].media.m, {
                   type: 'image/jpeg'
               }));
               if (i === data.items.length - 1) {
                   loadImages();
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. FileReader code below. Could someone explain the logic behind this code, it works but I am not that experienced in just JavaScript? Why is the data from the files array given twice?

   ```
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = (function (file) {
       return function (f) {
           // do something with the image...
           // f.target.result gets the value used for the src attribute
           // what do I need to do here to convert it into a File object that is equal to a typical file upload?
       };
   }) (files[i]); // why?
   reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]); // why again?
   ```

Thank you!

Kind regards
Richard

Comment: File objects are like refs to actual files. Use `FileReader()` to get the actual data, or `URL.createObjectURL()` to turn the actual data into a url. Note that since `File`s are "refs", using the OS to modify an open file will live-update the details of the `File` object, and you can re-read the `File` to get that new file data, without re-acquiring (via browser or dnd) the link. I believe it's this capability to "refresh" open objects that forces the initial  file to NOT have actual binary data upon acquisition.

Comment: Try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery/12282163#12282163

Comment: I actually used FileReader before (check the above), but how do I now convert it into a File object as if it was an upload? Thank you both for your help! :)