# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been getting this weird error and I just can't figure it out

Here is my current code:

```
function addBackground() {
   var penguin_id = getPenguinID();
   var file = $('#image_form')[0].files[0];
   console.log('Image Getting Uploaded');
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: "custBG.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.status == 0) {
                console.log('Image Has Been Uploaded');
                addBGItem(70000 + penguin_id);
        } else {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the form

```
<form id="image_form">
<div class="left">
<img id="img-uploaded" src="http://dummyimage.com/210x210/dbdbdb/7e7f80.png" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div class="right">
<input type="file" name="imageToUpload" accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg,.gif" onchange="validate_image()">
<span class="btn btn-large btn-alpha" onclick="addBackground()">Upload Image</span>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm not sure what's up but can anyone help me out with the problem.

Comment: What line of code is giving you that error?

Comment: It doesn't tell me but here http://prntscr.com/bhrmx9

Comment: It does: line 2 (inline-fe9e22321d.js: **2**), which I assume is `var file = $('#image_form')[0].files[0];` due to the nature of the error. Mind posting what's in `#image_form` in your DOM?

Comment: What do you see when you click on 'inline-.js:2'

Comment: This is what's in #image_form `<form id="image_form">
`

Comment: I need you to post everything between `<form>` and `</form>`, including the tags, in your OP.

Comment: In your OP please.

Comment: Original post. I'm asking you to edit the post where you have your JS and add the HTML as extra information, because it's relevant to help you.

Comment: Form elements don't have a `files` property. Try `$("#image_form input[type='file']")[0].files[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `$('#image_form')[0].files[0];` try with `$('#image_form').prop('files')[0];`
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In jQuery, using an id selector (such as `$('#image_form')`) will only yield the first result, so the `[0]` next to it is unneeded.</strike> (Forget that, an id selector [will always yield a collection no matter how many items there are](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) - Thanks Leo for bringing it up.) Moreover, it has no property `files`, which will yield yet another error.

What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want it to retrieve the encoded json errors from custBG.php

Comment: I mean, in the line that says `var file = $('#image_form')[0].files[0];`

Comment: The `<input type="files">` element should have a `files` property, but the `<form>` doesn't. So `$("#image_form input[type='file']")[0].files[0]` should "work" in the sense of fixing that particular line of code.

Comment: Oh it should get the file which has been uploaded

Comment: Perhaps [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery) will help you understand how to query for files.

Comment: @nnnnnn are you sure it works like that, out of the box? I've been reading it's not as simple.

Comment: @Abhishek may have it right with that post. Shall we mark this as duplicate?

Comment: Wrong. `$(selector)` will always return an array-like **jQuery wrapped collection**, no matter how many matched elements, or what type the selector is. For example `$('#app')` will return something like `[div#app, context: document, selector: "#app"]`.

Comment: My bad, I overread the docs do say $() with an id selector returns a **collection** of zero or one elements. Will edit my answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies in the `files[0]` I believe. perhaps you are trying to get the value in the input field? you're acquiring a jquery set of the firm, on which the files property is undefined. `$("#image_form").find("input").val()` should give you the input box value, though there may be a more appropriate way when dealing with forms

Comment: which is this line `console.log(data.message);`

Comment: Never-mind I fixed it; the problem was that it didn't have the dataType which is Json