# JSON data in a file

Tags: jquery, json

I found a code snippet showing how to fetch data from a JSON array:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
var data={"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"Ray",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "joined":2012
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "joined":2010
    }
]}

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.users[0].firstName + "    " + data.users[0].lastName+" "+ data.users[0].joined;
</script>
```

But I want the data in a JSON File. So how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from file input in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery)

Comment: So make an Ajax request and get the JSON file.

Comment: @nafas how is that even close to a duplicate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file and this documentation for making an AJAX request to get JSON from a URL http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('example.json', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I need the parameter "function" . For the local test I use a chrome extension (enable cross-origin resource sharing).