# Submitting file, and then calling function using the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to submit a .tsv file and then using d3.js to convert the .tsv file. (That later on will be used to plot a graph)

The d3.js is returning 404 file not found, is it the submit that is not working, or am I not calling the d3.tsv method correctly.
Feels like its trying to execute the d3 part before I select the file

Edit: Added .submit for the #file-input

```js
$('#fileSubmit').on('click', function() {
  $('#file-input').trigger('click');
  $('#file-input').on('change', function(){
    $('#file-input').submit()(function{
      alert("Submited!");
       d3.tsv($('#file-input.'), function(data){console.log(data);})
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="fileSubmit">Open</button>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />

</body>
```

Comment: When the user clicks the button `#fileSubmit` the file won't have been loaded...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Don't get it, you mean when the file is selected its not auto-submitted? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The 404 seems to confirm that.

Comment: Really struggling to understand, is there something missing then? Once the user selects a file, I want to process it. I have edited in the submit part but still same error...

Comment: This is wrong - `$('#file-input').submit()(function{ ... })` - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't need a `.submit()` function:

```
$('#fileSubmit').on('click', function() {
  $('#file-input').trigger('click');
  $('#file-input').on('change', function(){
      alert("Submited!");
      /* I don't know how d3 works so not sure what this is supposed to do */
      d3.tsv($('#file-input'), function(data){console.log(data);})
  });
});
```

Comment: d3.tsv(myFile.tsv, function(data){console.log(data);})
So the file that I select needs to go into the d3.tsv() - then i will plot graphs from it

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3305937

Comment: Ok, have a look at this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery