# How to submit form data text and images using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send an image data from Ajax to PHP, 
I have set the form enc-type to "multipart/form-data".

It sends the text, however, how do I send the file to a .php script?

The line, I am sending the image is

```
employee_picture = $("#employee_picture").val();
```

I believe I need to change the **.val()** to something else, however I don't have the current knowledge to solve the problem.

The Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (event) {
            $("#create_employee").attr("disabled", true);
            event.preventDefault();
            var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
            var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var dob = $("#dob").val();
            var other_information = $("#other_information").val();
            var gender = $("#gender").val();
            var address = $("#address").val();
            var address2 = $("#address2").val();
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var postal_code = $("#postal_code").val();
            var e_first_name = $("#e_first_name").val();
            var e_last_name = $("#e_last_name").val();
            var e_phone = $("#e_phone").val();
            var e_relationship = $("#e_relationship").val();
            var employee_picture = $("#employee_picture").val();
            var create_employee = $("#create_employee").val();
            $(".formMessage").load("/app/business/create_employee.php", 
            {
                csrf_token: csrf_token,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                email: email,
                phone: phone,
                title: title,
                dob: dob,
                other_information: other_information,
                gender: gender,
                address: address,
                address2: address2,
                city: city,
                postal_code: postal_code,
                e_first_name: e_first_name,
                e_last_name: e_last_name,
                e_phone: e_phone,
                e_relationship: e_relationship,
                employee_picture: employee_picture,
                create_employee: create_employee
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, in the php script. How can I access it using $_POST or $_FILES?
Thank you!

Comment: What type of DOM element is `#employee_picture`? Is it a file input, an img tag, etc.

Comment: @akenion it's a input type of file

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you do not want to use `val`. You can use the FileReader API(assuming browser support allows it) to actually get the file contents from the file input. See this question for details: [Get data from file input in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery)

You can pass that value as you are doing now and it will just be a string in the form data accessible in the `$_POST` array server-side. Typically, this will be a base64 encoded value.

If you did a plain form submission(not through AJAX), you would need to use the `$_FILES` array.

Also, you may want to look at using [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) or [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) rather than [`$.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/). I believe `$.load` will do a GET request when you really mean to do a POST.