# File Upload to remote server using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have an `HTML` form in my website and there is one file upload field in that form. When this form is submitted, I want to upload the selected file to the server and save it in the database. I have done the `php` part of uploading a file but I can not figure out the way how to send my file to that `api` that I created? I tried doing this:

```
var myFile = $("#picture_field").files[0];
```

and then send this variable as a `parameter` of my `ajax` request but I get the `error` which says:

> TypeError: $(...).files is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from file input in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281775/get-data-from-file-input-in-jquery)

Comment: @EinLinuus Quick question. I want to send data to my api in a non-json way from my ajax request because in my api, I am doing $_POST['param1'] and I don't want to use json_decode(receivedData); So how can I do that? I want to keep receiving the data in my php file like this: $_POST['param1'] and so on.

Comment: $.ajax({ url: "url-here.php", method: 'POST', data: {name: 'John', age: 20} }) the data object is the data passed as post data

Comment: @EinLinuus I am doing exactly like this but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#picture_field').prop('files')[0]
```

Above line does exactly what I was looking for.